# adding the use of multiple variables to an ob_start function

Tags: php

I've got the following object start code; however, right now it only uses 1 variable ( `$online` ) ....  I need to add a second variable ( `$var2` ) to the code so that I can have `"var2"=> $var2` under  `"online"=> $online`.  This needs to be added to the first line of code around where `use (&$online)` so the code knows the use this variable.

```
ob_start(function($c) use (&$online){
    $replacements = array(
        "online"=> $online
    );
    return preg_replace_callback("/{(\w+)}/",function($m) use ($replacements) {
        return isset($replacements[$m[1]]) ? $replacements[$m[1]] : $m[0];
    },$c);
});
```

How do I add this?  Everything I try breaks the code completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many variables to a `use` as you like, just separate them as you would parameters:

```
function($c) use (&$online,&$var2)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I will accept your answer in 10 minutes when stackoverflow allows me to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Following the php documentation on [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), you should use commas. Following the php documentation on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), you should also use commas there. Next time *try* looking it up. The php manual has lots of resources on this subject.

```
ob_start( function($c) use (&$online, &$var2){
  $replacements = array(
    "online"=> $online,
    "var2" => $var2,
 );
// ...
```